# getting information outside of .observe method in swift Firebase

Tags: xcode

So i was able to retrieve all data from my **firebase** database using the following function. I was wondering if there is a way i can save the output which is "`print(name)`" in the `self.GetUsername`  into a global variable

```
func GetUsername(uid:String , completion: @escaping ([Int]) -> ()) {
        Database.database().reference().child("Songs").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in
            var array: [Int] = []
            for item in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
            {
                array.append(item.value as! Int)

            }
            completion(array)

        }
    }

self.GetUsername(uid: (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!) { (name) in
            print(name)
        }
```

Comment: here's all the code :

Comment: self.GetUsername(uid: (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!) { (name) in
            print(name)
        }func GetUsername(uid:String , completion: @escaping ([Int]) -> ()) {
        Database.database().reference().child("Songs").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in
            var array: [Int] = []
            for item in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
            {
                array.append(item.value as! Int)
                
            }
            completion(array)
           
        }
    }